# Convergence of Polynomials in a Given Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been working on a rather tough problem related to sums of infinite series.
Say that I have a sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} c_j$ that converges, and say that I
have a polynomial $p(x)$ that has no constant term. I want to show that
$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} p(c_j)$ converges, although I don't quite know where to
move with this problem. Should I try to fix a particular $N$ such that for all
$n \geq m > N,$ and $\epsilon > 0,$ $|\sum_{i=m}^{n} c_j| < \epsilon$? Or do
I need to bound it with something smaller, potentially dependent on $p$?

Comment: $p$ must have the form $p(x) = x q(x)$ for some polynomial $q$. Since $c_j \to 0$, we might expect the terms to 'look' like $c_j q(0)$ for large $j$.

Comment: Is $\sum c_j$ meant to be absolutely convergent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, it seems that the problem is actually false. Take a very slowly converging, but *conditionally* convergent series like $ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^n / n^{0.01}$ and the polynomial $p(x) = x^2 + x$. Then we get a divergent series due to the influence of the divergent series

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{0.02}}$$

---

Now if you assume that the series is absolutely convergent, there is a positive result; it follows from the fact that $|c_n|^k < |c_n|$ eventually for each $k > 1$, implying absolute convergence of
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} c_n^k$$

Now a polynomial is a (finite) linear combination of such convergent series, which is still absolutely convergent.

Comment: Shouldn't 0.02 be 1.01 ?

Comment: @mercio No, I don't think so: We have $$\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{0.01}}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{(n^{0.01})^2} = \frac{1}{n^{0.02}}$$

Comment: In fact, $\sum_n (-1)^n {1 \over \sqrt{n}}$ is convergent, but with $p(x) = x^2$ we see that $\sum_n {1 \over n}$ is divergent.